# Working with arrays assembler 8086

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, x86-16, emu8086

Define an array with ten 16-bit words. Read the values of a string containing any characters from the keyboard. Afterwards, the string should be transformed, so that it should remain only elements that are lowercase letters (`a` - `z`).
Then, print the string out on the screen and store in the register `CX` the number of elements of the modified sequence.

This is my code:

```
data segment
array dw 10 dup (?) 
i db ?
ends

stack segment
dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment

start:

mov i, 0d    
mov bx, 0h
insert: ;inserting elements in array work only for db, but i need to work for dw
mov ah, 01h
int 21h 
mov array [bx], al
inc bx
inc i
cmp i,4d
JNE insert

mov bx, 0h
mov cl, i
go:  ; loop for finding numbers or same character who are not lowercase letters, deleting,
         ; and moving lowercase letters on their positions  
mov ax, array[bx]
cmp ax, 97d
jl notchar
cmp ax, 97d
jg notchar

loop go

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h  

ends

end start
```

My problem is, it doesn't work correctly with `dw`. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Google's yo' friend. First post your code.

Comment: I post my code in my question help me...please

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? How do you know it doesn't work? What do you mean with it doesn't work with `dw`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: when i insert a character from keyboard because dw is 2bytes i can write it in [bx] .
that instruction work only for db    ( mov array [bx], al ), i want to save dw in array no db

if i define array db 10 it's ok
but array dw 10 doesn't work, emu8086 gives me a error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing that stands in your way to store a word in stead of a byte in the array.

```
insert: ;inserting elements in array work only for db, but i need to work for dw
  mov ah, 01h
  int 21h 
  mov ah, 0            ;ADD THIS LINE
  mov array [bx], ax   ;CHANGE AL TO AX
  add bx, 2            ;ADD 2 BECAUSE THE ARRAY CONSIST OF WORDS
  inc i
  cmp i, 4
  JNE insert
```

The second part of your program needs some modification:

```
  mov ax, array[bx]    ;USE ONLY AL, AH=0
  cmp al, 97           ;ASCII FOR 'a'
  jb notchar           ;USE UNSIGNED COMPARISON, SO USE 'JB'
  cmp al, 97+25        ;ASCII FOR 'z'
  ja notchar           ;USE UNSIGNED COMPARISON, SO USE 'JA'
```